# AWS Glue java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

We are trying to use AWS Glue for our ETL process. While running AWS Glue job process is being killed due to Out of memory error.

```
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Mon Jan 08 20:35:34 +0000 2018
LogLength:129
Log Contents:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
# Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 6635"...
End of LogType:stdout
```

And I am not sure if I can set Java heap size in AWS Glue.

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your ETL job?

Comment: Can you please provide more details like what is your input size and How many DPU you have used for your job ?

Comment: Hi ashutosh and Kalyan, I have already solved this issue. The problem was with of the data read in ETL job. It was a json object with circular references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was causing due to circular reference JSON document in source.